# UITableView scroll freezes when scrolling fast

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, custom-cell

I am using custom tableview cells in a tableview. The data is loaded from the server and height calculation of that particular cell is done inside the cell only.

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h-FjYkSBuNM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am attaching the code for tableview cell for row at indexpath, custom cell method and code for get request.

```
    class QuesAnsFeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = questionLabel.frame.width
        self.answerLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = answerLabel.frame.width
        super.layoutSubviews()

    }
    func setup(){

        topLeftLabel = UILabel()
        topLeftLabel.font = UIFont(name: regularFont, size: 12)
        topLeftLabel.text = "Yesterday"
        topLeftLabel.textColor = CommonFunctions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: lightGray)

        topRightLabel = UILabel()
        topRightLabel.font = UIFont(name: regularFont, size: 12)
        topRightLabel.textColor = CommonFunctions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: lightGray)
        topRightLabel.text = ""
        topRightLabel.textAlignment = .right

        questionLabel = UILabel()
        questionLabel.font = UIFont(name: mediumFont, size: 14)
        questionLabel.text = "First Ques Comes Here and ans will be below this question"
        questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        questionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping


        userImageView = UIImageView()
        userImageView.backgroundColor = .purple
        userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(sidePadding)/2
        userImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        userNameLabel = UILabel()
        userNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: regularFont, size: 12)
        userNameLabel.text = ""

        answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.font = UIFont(name: regularFont, size: 14)
        answerLabel.text = ""
        answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        answerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        viewOtherAnswerLabel = UILabel()
        viewOtherAnswerLabel.font = UIFont(name: mediumFont, size: 12)
        viewOtherAnswerLabel.text = ""
        viewOtherAnswerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        viewOtherAnswerLabel.textColor = CommonFunctions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: lightGray)


        writeAnswerLabel = UILabel()
        writeAnswerLabel.font = UIFont(name: mediumFont, size: 14)
        writeAnswerLabel.backgroundColor = CommonFunctions.hexStringToUIColor(hex: crispBlue)
        writeAnswerLabel.text = "Write Answer"
        writeAnswerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        writeAnswerLabel.textColor = .white


        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tappedCell(sender:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)



//        self.addSubview(likeButton)
//        self.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    }
    func updateData(data:NSDictionary) -> CGFloat{
        if let viewCount = data["vc"] {
            topRightLabel.text = "\(viewCount) read"
        }

        if let ques = data["q"] as? String{
            topLeftLabel.frame = CGRect(x:sidePadding/2, y: 2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth/2-sidePadding, height: Int(CommonFunctions.calculateHeight(inString: topLeftLabel.text!, forFont: topLeftLabel.font, andWidthOfLabel: CGFloat(screenWidth/2))))
            topRightLabel.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth/2, y: 2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth/2-sidePadding/2, height: Int(topLeftLabel.frame.height))

            let newHeight = CommonFunctions.calculateHeight(inString: ques,forFont:questionLabel.font,andWidthOfLabel:questionLabel.frame.width)


            questionLabel.frame = CGRect(x:sidePadding/2 ,y: Int(topLeftLabel.frame.maxY)+sidePaddingForCollectionCells,width: screenWidth - sidePadding, height: Int(ceil(Float(newHeight))))
            questionLabel.text = ques
            self.addSubview(topLeftLabel)
            self.addSubview(topRightLabel)
            self.addSubview(questionLabel)

//            questionLabel.attributedText = CommonFunctions.justifiedText(string: ques)
        }
        if let user = data.object(forKey: "user") as? NSDictionary{
            if let usrName = user.value(forKey: "name"){
                userNameLabel.text = "\(usrName)"

            }
            if let imgLink = user["image"] as? String{
                if let url = URL(string: imgLink){
                    userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url,placeholderImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholderImage"))
                }
            }



        }
        if let otherAnswer = data.value(forKey: "cc") {
            viewOtherAnswerLabel.text = "View Other Answer \(otherAnswer)"
        }

        if let ans = data.value(forKey: "comt") as? String{
            answered = true
            userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: sidePadding/2, y: Int(questionLabel.frame.maxY)+2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: sidePadding, height: sidePadding)
            userNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 3*sidePadding/2+2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, y:Int(questionLabel.frame.maxY)+sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth-2*sidePadding, height: Int(topLeftLabel.frame.height))



            let newHeight = CommonFunctions.calculateHeight(inString: ans,forFont:answerLabel.font,andWidthOfLabel:answerLabel.frame.width)
            let frame = CGRect(x: 3*sidePadding/2+2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, y:Int(userNameLabel.frame.maxY) + sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth-2*sidePadding-2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, height: Int(ceil(Float(newHeight))))
            answerLabel.frame = frame
            answerLabel.text = ans

            viewOtherAnswerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: Int(answerLabel.frame.maxY)+2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth, height: 2*sidePadding/3)


            self.addSubview(userImageView)
            self.addSubview(userNameLabel)
            self.addSubview(answerLabel)
            self.addSubview(viewOtherAnswerLabel)
            writeAnswerLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            return viewOtherAnswerLabel.frame.maxY
        }
        else{
            answered = false
            writeAnswerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:Int(questionLabel.frame.maxY) + 2*sidePaddingForCollectionCells, width: screenWidth, height: sidePadding)
            self.addSubview(writeAnswerLabel)
            userImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            userNameLabel.removeFromSuperview()

            answerLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            viewOtherAnswerLabel.removeFromSuperview()

            return writeAnswerLabel.frame.maxY
        }

    }
```

TableView Code

```
class GenericView: UIView ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView:UITableView!
    var viewFrame = CGRect()
    var parentView = ""
    var discussViewHeight = [Int:CGFloat]()
    var nextUrlPath = ""
    var currentUrlPath = ""
    private var sliderLabelsText = ["Favourites","Sign In"]

    private var tableBlocks = [NSDictionary]()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        viewFrame = frame
        setup()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        if viewFrame != CGRect() {
            setup()
        }
    }
    public func updateView(){
        viewFrame = self.frame
        tableView.frame = (viewFrame)

        getRequest()
    }

    func getRequest(){
        currentUrlPath = baseUrl+nextUrlPath
             if parentView == discussView{
//            let url = baseUrl + nextUrlPath
            Alamofire.request(currentUrlPath).responseJSON { response in
                if let dict = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    if (dict["msc"]) as? String == "700", let blocks = dict["blocks"] as? NSArray{
                        self.nextUrlPath = (dict["next"] as? String ?? "")
                        for block in blocks{
                            if let blk = block as? NSDictionary{

                                if blk.value(forKey: "ty") as? String == "qa"{
                                    self.tableBlocks.append(blk)
                                }
                                appDelegate.tableBlocks.append(blk)

                            }

                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            self.currentUrlPath = ""
                            self.getRequest()
                        })

                    }


                }
            }
            return

        }

    }

    func setup(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tableView = UITableView(frame: viewFrame, style: .grouped)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.addSubview(tableView)
        registerCells()

    }



    //MARK: TableView DataSource Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if parentView == discussView{

            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if parentView == discussView{
            return tableBlocks.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (parentView == discussView){
            var cell:QuesAnsFeedTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: quesAnsFeedViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? QuesAnsFeedTableViewCell

            if (cell == nil){
                cell = QuesAnsFeedTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: quesAnsFeedViewCellIdentifier)
            }
            cell?.selectionStyle = .none
            discussViewHeight[indexPath.section] = (cell?.updateData(data: tableBlocks[indexPath.section]))!
            cell?.setNeedsLayout()
            cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell!
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    //MARK: TableView Delegate Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


        if parentView == discussView{
            return discussViewHeight[indexPath.section] ?? 0
        }
        return 0
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       if parentView == discussView{
            return sectionHeaderView
        }
        return UIView()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if parentView == discussView && indexPath.section+5 > tableBlocks.count{
            if currentUrlPath != baseUrl + nextUrlPath{
                getRequest()
            }

        }


    }
}
```

I have deleted some code from classes just to keep the size of question small.

The call for next fetch will depend on the indexpath of cell which is currently being displayed and the function which fetches the content from server will be getRequest().

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using footer views and dynamic heights?

Comment: no footer is set with height = 0, and yes I am using dynamic heights. 
Although, I have found the workaround by changing part of willDisplayCell-

        if parentView == discussView && indexPath.section+**3** > tableBlocks.count{
            if currentUrlPath != baseUrl + nextUrlPath{
                getRequest()
    }

But I am still interested in a better solution if possible.

Comment: May be you are downloading thumbnails or some extra looping on main thread

Comment: Also prefer lazy coding I.e. Code only for methods which are required this ma help you in future as clean code is easy to debug

Comment: no thumbnails are downloaded using the sdwebimage which fetches asynchronously. and other api related calls are made using alamofire.